# Facebook - retrieving comment-count and likes-count?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have a  table with Facebook Post id. using this post id I want to retrieve post's comments count and likes count.

Any hint is very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I don't have much idea about FB API method. Which method will result this two counts?

Answer (score 1):

USE FQL

select likes.count, comments.count FROM stream WHERE post_id =POST_ID

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into the `Facebook API` and atleast do some research before posting here.

This should give you some insight : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Use the API to get the array response from `Facebook` based on the `post`. Then look through it to find the counts you desire.

You will need to obtain an `access_token` from `Facebook` in order to make an requests against the `Facebook Graph`. There are also plenty of tutorials and snippits out there when researched.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like this as the URL to fetch what you need:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/albumID/photos?fields=id,likes.summary(true),comments.summary(true)&access_token=XXXXXX
```

I don't really know what you mean by a table but here is [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32085722/how-to-count-all-of-the-likes-and-comments-in-a-facebook-photo-album) that details a similar problem.